parent travel history reflecting on son?
If my mother has been to the UK multiple times, has a good travel history like schengen, America etc..
will this kind of travel history reflect well on her 18 year old son if he wants to try to travel with her to the UK? reflect well, as in increase visa approval chances. and avoid overstaying suspicion

This question is similar to: last year of school - UK visit visa. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

it is indeed different, I want to know if travel history will reflect well on me or not.

Why would it reflect on you? Your risk profile is completely different.

@Hellomsm It will have no bearing either way.

I'm not sure I agree with the others. While it is difficult to say if they have any chance of considering it, it they do, it should reflect positively. If the parents have had the means to make multiple uneventful trips in the past, their own, school/student-age son, which probably relies on their sponsorship, seems quite unlikely to become an illegal immigrant. But given you probably rely on their sponsorship, their financials are probably more important.

I think @jcaron is correct, OTOH I do not think travel history is an important factor, so parent travel history is just a small bonus (and just because the son is travelling with the mother). So I would not count on it to get the visa. Mother experience on visa application may be much more relevant.

that makes sense, appreciate it. I've successfully gotten a visa with her at the age of 17 which isn't really far from 18 either. I've travelled with her to the UK once on that visa. wouldn't that also reflect positively on me as well? especially that she's travelling with me again. or is my travel history under 18 useless?

If you're unemployed and young (reasonably school age), then you will benefit from

Traveling with your (employed) mom
Having your family cover your expenses
Briefly mentioning your mom's travel history to the UK on your visa form
Having your mom present her travel history if border officer is distrustful

To be clear: This helps, but is in no way a guarantee. 18 is, unfortunately, almost definitely the riskiest age that can apply for a visa. If you applied with no sponsor and for traveling alone, you'd have a very, very low chance of approval.

UK visa form gives you several places to fill that will reflect more positively on you:
You can state that you will be traveling with your mom:

And as you said you're 18, you can state that she will be paying for the costs of your trip, and later when uploading documents, provide appropriate documentation (official guidance for which documents can be found here):

And finally, you can mention that your mom traveled to the UK multiple times and that she already has a UK visa (if she does, that is) in the "Extra information" section:

This should maximize your chances by making it clear that your family has proven financial means for this trip (reducing perceived risk of overstay), and that your mom has the knowledge and means to make sure this trip is, from the perspective of UK, uneventful.

I've successfully gotten a visa with her at the age of 17 which isn't really far from 18 either. I've travelled with her to the UK once on that visa. wouldn't that also reflect positively on me as well? especially that she's travelling with me again. or is my travel history under 18 useless?

@Hellomsm you will need to state your travel history on your application, the fact that you did go to UK and leave on time before should reflect a bit positively. A major part of visa applications involves examining your material conditions and deciding based on that, and even if you were a great traveler for your last 10 travels, if something on your application indicates you're likely to overstay (for ex. if you are now unemployed and have a partner on the country you're trying to visit), you might still be rejected.

appreciate it! thank you for taking the time to explain and giving me the good and bad about it, it's definitely better than having people straight up telling me "you're getting rejected good luck"
